# Circuit Design for 6 LEDs flashing in sequence

Tags: led

I am helping my son with his school project.  He wants to design a circuit which has a on and off button and has 6 LEDS and each LED flashes for 20 seconds and stay on, and then the next LED will follow the same sequence. What would i need to do this ? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what does "son" learn when "dad" figures it all out for him ? Will you be there also to assist him on his first job ? When I was a kid I could make a 2 LED flashing circuit by myself. I mean, it's better for a kid to make something he figured out all by himself then something fancy but "dad" did all the work.

Comment: Buy him an arduino nano, 5V supply,  on/off switch, 6 * leds, 6* 1k0 resistors, connecting wire and a prototyping (plug in type) board, then let him work it out. He'll get a kick from doing it himself as well as learning an important life lesson - its the journey that's important, not the destination.

Answer (score 2):

Getting 20 second timing with RCs is non-trivial. Consider looking at an HC4060, which is a VCO with built in divider, designed for long period timing.

Depending on what your son is supposed to achieve during 'his' design, you may then want to look at either a binary counter like HC161 + decoder like HC138, or look at a 'one-hot' coded state machine, built from D flops like HC74. I think the latter would be better suited to his needs.

You may also want to look up 'Johnson Counter', and shift registers like the HC164.

However, from experience, I can say that 'helping' your son with his tech homework by introducing him to stuff several levels above his ken is simply counterproductive. If you can point him at the data sheets, then stay the heck out, there's a better chance that he might learn somthing.